# Looking for short story about a short-story-generator

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was called something like "The Greatest Science Fiction Story" or something like that. Some physicist makes a story that resolves into the best possible short story for the person who first reads it, or something. He sends it into an agent, and when the agent opens it he sees a verbatim copy of *Nightfall* by Asimov

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"[The greatest science-fiction story ever written](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v467/n7319/full/4671146a.html)" by Eric James Stone

> I opened it.
>
> “Read it out loud,” Caleb said.
>
> I looked past my name and began reading. “In my opinion, this is the
>   greatest science-fiction story ever written.” My heart leapt within
>   me, and I continued. “It is undoubtedly the best story you have ever
>   submitted to me. But what on Earth made you think you could get away
>   with submitting a verbatim copy of 'Nightfall' by Isaac Asimov?”

Comment: "a blunt advertisement for 'Nightfall'" I thought. Then I read the story. I love it!

Comment: If you like this story, you will love "Needful things" from Stephen King where someone sells things. What he sells seems to be different to each buyer. But it's always what they secretly crave for.